# Downloading files using the Laravel download function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am beginner in Laravel.

I have this code:

```
$fileName = now()->toDateString() . '.docx';
$myFileName = 'Raport glowny'.docx;
        try {
            $objWriter->save(storage_path($fileName));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
        }

        return response()->download(storage_path($fileName));
```

I have 2 filenames:

$ fileName = now () -> toDateString (). '.Docx';
$ myFileName = 'Main Report'.docx;

$ fileName - the name of the file on the server's disk

$ myFileName - the name of the file with which I would like the file to be saved on the user's disk.

Is it possible to specify the name of the file in the download function?

If so, how to do it?

Comment: `$myFileName = 'Raport glowny'.docx;` is wrong, quotes are misplaced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass this name as second parameter:

```
return response()->download(storage_path($fileName), $myFileName)
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#file-downloads

Comment: thank you. Is posible remove $fileName after download?

Comment: @operloa Yes, you can add ```->deleteFileAfterSend()```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Response::download($path);`

```
   Route::get('files/{order_id}/{file_name}', function($order_id,$file_name)
{
    $path = storage_path().'/'.'app'.'/assets/OrderFiles/'.$order_id.'/attach/'.$file_name;
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return Response::download($path);
    }
})->name('GetAttachFile');
```